# Unable to upgrade iMac to Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard

I am unable to upgrade my iMac to Snow Leopard even though it seems to meet all the requirements. The iMac has:

- Intel Core 2 Duo processor
- DVD drive
- 4GB RAM
- 185GB of storage available.

When I try to install, it simply says "Mac OS X Snow Leopard cannot be installed on this computer."

Comment: What version of OSX are you currently using on your iMac (you can find out in  -> "About My Mac")? Does booting from the Snow Leopard DVD work (reboot with the DVD inserted, hold Alt/Option when the chime sounds)?

Comment: Are you trying got use a disc that came with a different Mac?

Comment: OS X 10.5.8. Yes, I am using the disk that came with my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a different disc and it worked. Apparently, the disc I originally tried was only to be used on the computer it came with.

Comment: Yes, the discs that come with a computer are keyed to only work with that specific model, you need to use a retail disc to upgrade another computer.